# SQL left join between three tables with union

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have Products, from many Brands, which a User can favorite (many-to-many) and also the User can follow Brands. And for the homepage I need all the products which the user has added to favorites and the products from Brands the User follows.

I have came with the following SQL query, which however, works not as expected -- it returns only products which are from followed brands and are in the same time in favorites.

```
SELECT * FROM products
INNER JOIN favorites ON products.id = favorites.favorable_id
INNER JOIN followings ON products.merchant_id = followings.followable_id
WHERE favorites.favorable_type = 'Product' AND favorites.user_id = ?
AND followings.followable_type = 'Merchant' AND followings.user_id = ?
```

How can I properly fix the query?
Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I will have 10k+ products, 1k+ users. So I need the fastest in execution time query.

Comment: I also need to be able to paginate the results, therefore I am not sure whether UNION is the best solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One 'simple' approach (just modifying your existing query) could be to turn both of your `INNER JOIN`s into `LEFT JOIN`s and check that `at least one of the two joined successfully` in the `WHERE` clause...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  products
LEFT JOIN
  favorites
    ON  products.id = favorites.favorable_id
    AND favorites.favorable_type = 'Product'
    AND favorites.user_id = ?
LEFT JOIN
  followings
    ON  products.merchant_id = followings.followable_id
    AND followings.followable_type = 'Merchant'
    AND followings.user_id = ?
WHERE
      favorites.user_id IS NOT NULL
  OR followings.user_id IS NOT NULL
```

This has the downside that ***every*** record in the `product` table has to be checked by the `WHERE` clause.

If that table is small, or you normally return a 'large' fraction of the table any way, this may be fine.  If you, however, only return a 'small' fraction of the table, you may want to optimise this, such as using two queries with a `UNION`, as implied by your question title...

```
SELECT
  products.*
FROM
  products
INNER JOIN
  favorites
    ON  products.id = favorites.favorable_id
    AND favorites.favorable_type = 'Product'
    AND favorites.user_id = ?

UNION

SELECT
  products.*
FROM
  products
INNER JOIN
  followings
    ON  products.merchant_id = followings.followable_id
    AND followings.followable_type = 'Merchant'
    AND followings.user_id = ?
```

Each `INNER JOIN` here may be significantly faster than the whole of the `LEFT JOIN` based query, due to potentially being able to use indexes on `followings(user_id, followable_type)` and `favorites(user_id, favorable_type)`.

Comment: But if I need to apply additional filters to the two queries and limit the entire union isn`t this going to dramatically slow down the query? I will have 10000+ products

Comment: @DimitarVouldjeff - That can be done by using the above queries as a sub query...  `SELECT * FROM ( <one of the queries from above> ) AS product INNER JOIN x ON blah = blah` for example.  In terms of performance, using this as a sub-query shouldn't make it any worse, but you're always best advised to test it.

Comment: I mean, which is in your opinion the faster query --- with joins or with a union?

Comment: @DimitarVouldjeff - If there are 10000 products, and the results of the query give you 9000 of them, then the `LEFT JOIN` will likly be faster.  If there are 10000 products, and the results of the query give you 10 of them, then the `UNION` will likely be faster; provided that you create the two indexes that I mentioned - `followings(user_id, followable_type)` and `favorites(user_id, favorable_type)`.

Comment: It will probably return 2000... then?

Comment: @DimitarVouldjeff - There is only one way to be sure...  Test it.

Comment: Yes, I will, but the thing is that my current database does not include followings... and I have to setup testing environments

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace the

```
 INNER JOIN followings ON products.merchant_id = followings.followable_id
```

with

```
left JOIN followings ON favorites.favorable_id = followings.followable_id
```

Comment: You need to do this to *both* `INNER JOIN`s, and then you need to move part of the `WHERE` clause into the join predicate, and add an additional condition to the `WHERE` clause.  In short, this is currently a very incomplete answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
select p.*
from products as p
where
    exists (
       select *
       from favorites as f
       where f.favorable_id = p.id and f.favorable_type = 'Product' and f.user_id = ?
    ) or
    exists (
       select *
       from followings as f
       where f.followable_id = p.merchant_id and f.followable_type = 'Merchant' and f.user_id = ?
    )
```

Comment: How does PostGreSQL optimise `EXISTS() OR EXISTS()`?  Will this yield a full table scan of `products`, even if each `EXISTS()` is highly selective?  *(Also, the last `p.id` needs to be `p.merchant_id`.)*

Comment: @MatBailie: it's PostgreSQL (or simply Postgres), but never PostGreSQL

Comment: @MatBailie exists will use indexes if there're indexes on favorable_id / followable_id  (and types)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM products p
LEFT JOIN favorites ON products.id = favorites.favorable_id and favorites.favorable_type = 'Product' AND favorites.user_id = ?
LEFT JOIN followings ON products.merchant_id = followings.followable_id and followings.followable_type = 'Merchant' AND followings.user_id = ?
WHERE favorites.user_id is not null or followings.user_id is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
select p.*
from products as p
where
p.id in (
       select f.favorable_id
       from favorites as f
       where  f.favorable_type = 'Product' and f.user_id = ?
)
or p.merchant_id in ( 
       select f.followable_id
       from followings as f
       where  f.followable_type = 'Merchant' and f.user_id = ?
)
```

Comment: `favourable_id` relates to `p.id`, but `followable_id` relates to `p.merchant_id`, you can't do this all in one `IN()` statement.